# How to calculate weighted mean

Tags: statistics, average, means

If i have interest rates for instance

1 week = 0.123%

1 month = 0. 345%

3 month =0.567%

6 month = 0.678%

12 month = 0.890%

how do you calculate 4month, 5month, 8 month, 10month?

Comment: The rates should be in a relation somehow. But I don´t see how. I doubt that the values make sense. It can be seen in the calculation below (answer of max_zorn). You should post additional information.

Answer (score 1):

To compare say, between 1 week and 1 month, you can start with the week rate and do $(1+0.00123)^4 = 1.004929085$ which is $0.4929 \%$. The geometric mean is the proper one to use: E.g., if you want to bring the 12-month rate to 1-month, you would do $(1+0.00890)^{1/12} = 1.00073866$ which is $0.07 \%$ per month.

Comment: Can u do most simplest way possible?

Comment: If u wanna calculate 4 months u just do (0.567*2+0.678)/3

Comment: Idk why we are multiplying by 2 to 3 month